# Find the ratios of the sides of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

If the perimeter of a the right-angle triangle is six times its smallest side,
find the ratios of the three sides.

I tried solving it by using the normal area and volume.

Comment: Try using algebra, instead. Give the sides names, and write down all the equations you can, and then solve for the ratios.

Comment: I would change the tags on this. Especially 'measure theory'. Seems to be a simple algebra question with an application to the sides of a right triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Start by making three lengths $a$, $b$, and $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.  Add these and set equal to $6a$ and solve for $b$ in terms of $a$. I'll leave the rest up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Let the sides be $a$,$b$, and $c$, with $a$ being the smallest side ad $c$ being the hypotenuse.

Using the Pythagoras theorem,
$$c^2=a^2+b^2$$
The given condition is
$$a+b+c=6a$$
Thus
$$b+c=5a$$
$$(b+c)^2=25a^2$$
$$b^2+c^2+2bc=25a^2$$
$$a^2+2b^2+2bc=25a^2$$
$$24a^2-2b^2=2bc$$
$$12a^2-b^2=bc$$
$$(12a^2-b^2)^2=(bc)^2$$
$$144a^4+b^4-24a^2b^2=b^2(a^2+b^2)=b^2a^2+b^4$$
$$144a^4=25a^2b^2$$
Since $a\ne0$,
$$144a^2=25b^2$$
That is,
$$12a=5b$$
or
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{5}{12}$$
$$c^2=a^2+b^2=(\frac{5}{12}b)^2+b^2$$
$$c^2=\frac{169}{144}b^2$$
$$c=\frac{13}{12}b$$
$$\frac{b}{c}=\frac{12}{13}$$
The ratio $a:b:c$ is thus $5:12:13$

Comment: Not leaving much for OP to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You have:
$$a+b+c=6a \Rightarrow a=\frac{b+c}{5}$$
so, from $a^2+b^2=c^2$, we have:
$$
(b+c)^2+25b^2=c^2 \Rightarrow 13\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^2+\frac{b}{c}-12=0
$$
Solve this equation and you find (only) one acceptable value $k$ for $\frac{b}{c}$

substitute $b=kc$ in the perimeter and find $\frac{a}{c}$

> $k=\frac{12}{13} \Rightarrow a:b:c=5:12:13$

Comment: That's not a Pythagorean triplet. I think the equation should be $$(b+c)^2+25b^2=25c^2$$

Comment: @GoodDeeds. Thanks! I had a stupid mistake! I fix ..:)